# Regex that doesn't match three endings

Tags: java, regex

How can I write a Java regex that matches lines that do not end in any of the three endings `abc`, `def`, ot `ghi`?

For example, the following cases should work as shown below:

```
1234abc     -- not valid  (ends with 'abc')
09mno       -- valid
ef          -- valid
def         -- not valid (ends with 'def')
hello       -- valid
helloghi    -- not valid (ends with 'ghi')
longertext  -- valid
```

Comment: Might the reverse be simpler? Match for `.*(?:abc|def|ghi)`, then you can do `!pattern.matches(string)`.

Comment: Deploying a new version of the java code (that `!`) to production is a big hassle. If possible, I would prefer to change the regex in the app settings instead. Anyway, I can deploy to prod, if there's no other option.

Answer (score 0):

just played a little in regex101.com and came up with this:

```
^(?!(.*(abc|def|ghi)$))
```

**Edit 25.10.2023**
added `.+$` to the end to not match an empty string

```
^(?!(.*(abc|def|ghi)$)).+$
```

Comment: Missing a `.*$` on the end of the pattern, otherwise this will match the empty string at the start of the line (since your lookahead just confirms what to match).